# i'm trying to remove the spaces around my header image and navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

i looked at all the similar questions and tried applying it to my situation but nothing seems to be working. the spaces above/bottom the header image i thought would be gone by adding `display: block;`.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("assets/images/richie-pic.jpg");
  font-size: 28px;
}

.mrrichie-img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #111111;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #313331;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="./assets/images/header.png" id="mrrichie-img" alt="header images">


<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a style="left: 350px;position: relative;" href="#music" class="active">Music</a>
  <a style="left: 350px;position: relative;" href="#videos">Videos</a>
  <a style="left: 750px;position: relative;" href="#merch">Merch</a>
  <a style="left: 750px;position: relative;" href="#aboutme">About me</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsG22.png) I am not sure if the `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0;` is affecting it but this was also on a solution i tried.

Comment: why dont you try `*{margin:0,padding:0}` and do further css.

I think normalizing solves your problem, so normalize before doing styling.

Ref link: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Ids selectors are `#` not `.` So you need to grab the element by writing `#mrrichie-img { ....`

Comment: are you talking about space between your header image and navbar?

Comment: its `#mrrichie-img {
  }` You messed with `id selector` and `class selector`

Answer (score 0):

just add `margin: 0` to the body, here's your example without the space , or you can make it more general by adding `*{margin: 0; padding: 0}` , by this you make sure all the elements don't have extra space across all browsers

https://codepen.io/engeslamadell/pen/LYNYPqo

Comment: thanks so much will apply this as i carry on, wow this website is amazing, such an helpful community

Answer (score 0):

There is a margin around the body element.

If you set the margin to 0, it should remove the space around the header images.

```
body{
   margin:0;
}
```